# Evaluate the triple integral in different ordrer.

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I'm trying to solve this problem;
[image]

First, I'm trying to solve this problem in order dzdydx.
In my opinion, the triple integral would be $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^\frac xy dzdydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac xydydx=\int_0^1x[lny]_0^1$ which is diverge.
Correct answer is 3/4 which is defintely converge. 
I think I had a mistake about the region but I can't find where is wrong.
Could you please help me which part is mistake and give some tips about interchanging the orders?

Comment: I think this is because when $x=0$ and $y=0$ then $z = x/y$ is not well-defined. But why do you need to change the order of integration?

Comment: @Willy.K There is no specific reason. I was practicing interchanging the order and thought it is always possible(at least the region).

Comment: I got it. Well, notice that some problems arise when $x=0$ or $y=0$, so this might be the reason why your integral is becoming divergent.

Comment: @Willy.K Thanks for answering. I think I should study Fubini's theorem.